# convert String to Clob in Java 1.4 oracle 10g

Tags: java, oracle

I am facing problem when trying to convert a String to Clob in Java code.
I am using java 1.4 and oracle 10g.

```
stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO RAWDATA_EQUIFAX (REQ_ID, BUREAU_CODE, RAWDATA, RESP_TIME) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
stmt.setClob(3, rawData); //rawData is String in java
```

The error I get is:

```
The method setClob(int, Clob) in the type PreparedStatement is not applicable for the arguments (int, String)
```

Comment: this is different case Aaron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use [`PreparedStatement#setCharacterStream(int, Reader, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setCharacterStream%28int,%20java.io.Reader,%20int%29)

```
Reader reader = new StringReader(rawData);
stmt.setCharacterStream(3, reader, rawData.length()); //or whicehver index
```

Upgrade to java 7.

Comment: I tried Clob clob = conn.createClob();     I got the error <<The method createClob() is undefined for the type Connection>> Here the connection is java.sql.Connection

Comment: See the javadoc for java.sql.Conntextion, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createClob(). You're probably using some other Connection class.

Comment: you gave the documentation for java 7. I am using java 1.4

Comment: @user215005 This version should work with 1.4, but you should really upgrade.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. I agree with you that the application should be upgraded to java 7.

Answer (score 0):

With 10g, you don't need CLOBs on the Java side anymore. Just set the connection property `SetBigStringTryClob` to `true` and use `Strings` in the JDBC API.

http://rocksolutions.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/handling-clobs-made-easy-with-oracle-jdbc-10g/